# Check if String is valid ArrayList

Tags: java

I might receive a `String` which actually is an `ArrayList` e.g.: `String x = "["one", "two"]";`

I would like to check whether or not the string is a valid ArrayList.

`if(key.startsWith("[") && key.endsWith("]"))` if statement works but I would like to know if there is another better approach?

Is there any better approach?

Comment: It depends - a valid "ArrayList" according to what syntax? Just as written there with strings, or is it something more general like a JSON array? (I'm assuming you wouldn't count "[][][]$!$![][]]]]" as valid, so the check you've outlined there won't really work.)

Comment: A `String` can **not** be an `ArrayList`. What you meant is, that the String could be an `Array.toString()`

Comment: You can implement (let's call it) checker with stack. Throw significant characters like '[ ] " ,' and check if all brackets, quation marks are closed.

Comment: This very much  depend on what the content is of the array in the string, is it always strings or number or can it be an array of arrays for instance?

Answer (score 0):

The `toString()` implementation of `ArrayList` comes from [AbstractCollection](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/AbstractCollection.java).

If you take a look at the function (near the bottom) you'll notice it uses a generic type `E` to append to the internal `StringBuilder`. This is because the code does not know what kind of elements you are going to put in the collection - it may be `String`s, as in your example, or it may be something more complex like `Map`s. It will try to call each element's internal `toString()` function and default to `Object`'s `toString()` method.

You can start by checking if the String begins and ends with square brackets `[` and `]`, but for anything further you will have to reverse-engineer the `toString()` method of whatever elements you are putting in your `ArrayList`.

The string representation of an `ArrayList<String>` (which seems to be your example above) does not quote its elements. Thus, since the `String` can include an arbitrary number of commas and spaces it is impossible to distinguish between elements. To illustrate this, consider the following scenario:

```
String s1 = "a, ";
String s2 = "b";
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(s1);
list.add(s2);
System.out.println(list.toString()); // [a, , b]
```

Are there two elements `a,` and `b` or two elements `a` and `, b`?